# Application hanging when contacting TCP listener inside a loop

Tags: c#, winforms, console, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have been trying to setup a client application which contacts a console server application using TCP sockets.

I need my client to constantly keep checking with the server "is there data available?" and at some point the server will respond with the data, that will be shown in the application on-screen.

The server app is a console based application and on the client is using winforms so that the user can click a button in the GUI and start the process. When the data is received I need it to show on the screen in a textbox.

The problem is that the winform application is hanging inside the loop. It's working but completely disabled and doesn't allow any button clicks and doesn't show the returned data on screen.

This is how I setup the client app:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8888);
    try
    {
        Stream s = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
        while (true)
        {
            tbData.Text = "Name: ";
            string name = textBox2.Text;
            sw.WriteLine(name);
            if (name != null)
            {
                tbData.Text = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        s.Close();

    }
    finally
    {
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it just sends a request every 5 seconds but I need that part to run in the background (providing that's the best method.

Comment: The UI thread is busy, not hanging.  Push it to a background thread for processing while the UI waits.  You should look into BackgroundWorker:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking the UI thread. Find out what that means and use any of the common techniques to unblock it.

When you run code on the UI thread the UI can't update for that period in time.